# O que é programação embarcada?

Tags: terminologia

Lendo um livro sobre práticas de programação, em um certo momento é citado um trecho sobre **programação embarcada**. Não chega a entrar em detalhes, mas fala um pouco sobre programação em **microcontroladores** e **microprocessadores**.

O que é uma programação embarcada? Existe uma linguagem específica para criar um sistema embarcado?

Comment: É quando o código fica a ver navios :p

Comment: Tem uma questão que foi removida do SOzão que trata bem disso :) http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/

Comment: Ainda bem que ninguém falou em Clipper e Harbour   /s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como o [MagicHat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45437) comentou em sua resposta, a programação embarcada é voltada a códigos que são executados em uma plataforma específica, geralmente tratando de um problema específico e suas práticas/técnicas diferem das utilizadas em aplicações desktop justamente por isso. Nas aplicações desktop é possível você ter bibliotecas genéricas, que resolvem um problema em *N* situações diferentes, isso porque você tem memória e espaço em disco praticamente ilimitados, ou seja, esbanja recursos computacionais. Em uma aplicação embarcada, o cenário já muda completamente. Por exemplo, na placa de desenvolvimento Arduino Uno, que utiliza o microcontrolador ATmega328P, você possui apenas 32 KB de memória Flash, 2 KB de SRAM e 1 KB de EEPROM, tudo isso rodando à um clock de 16 MHz. Seus recursos computacionais são extremamente limitados, por isso muda a forma de se projetar uma aplicação.

Sendo ela mais limitada, as linguagens de programação mais utilizadas são C e Assembly. C em plataformas que você possui mais memória e consegue trabalhar com um pouco mais de liberdade, como no Arduino, Assembly para quando você tem os recursos ainda mais limitados e precisa desenvolver uma solução muito específica.

Porém, você ainda consegue ter aplicações rodando sobre sistemas operacionas embarcados, como ocorre na plataforma Raspberry Pi. Existe uma distribuição Linux modificada justamente para ser embarcada na placa em que você consegue rodar basicamente qualquer linguagem de programação, tais como Python, PHP, Java, etc. É possível justamente porque tais plataformas possuem mais recursos de hardware disponíveis (hoje de 512 KB à 2 GB de RAM, no Raspberry, rodando a 900 MHz).

Answer (score 5):

Programação embarcada é o nome dado a programas direcionados a sistemas embarcados, que por sua vez, são aqueles que diferente de sistemas de uso geral,  são planejados para o uso de tarefas pré-definidas de uso específico, por exemplo um roteador.

São usadas linguagens de baixo-nível, em sua maioria C e Assembly.